# How do you solve for the largest value of x for which the acceleration is zero in this problem?

Tags: calculus, physics

This is my problem:

> A block of mass 1.50 kg is accelerated across a rough surface by a light cord passing over a small pulley shown in the image below. The tension T in the cord is maintained at 10.0 N, and the pulley is 0.140 m above the top of the block. The coefficient of kinetic friction is 0.360.

This is the question it is asking:

> Find the largest value of x for which the acceleration is zero.

I have been trying to solve this for hours with no luck, please help.

[Image of the problem here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yErPQ.jpg)

Edit: To further explain my problem and what I have tried:

> I know that to find x when acceleration = 0 you set the force of friction equation equal to force giving you Tcos(theta) = mu(mg - Tsin(theta) and then you put it in terms of x. I got (1/m)(mu)(m)(g)[x^2 + h^2]^-1/2 = (1/m)Tx + (1/m)(mu)(h)(T) (h being the height of the pulley). I then substitute in my variables m = 1.5kg, h = 0.14m, mu = 0.36, and T = 10N. I guess what I’m asking is if that equation is correct because it worked for a practice problem with different numbers but not the numbers in the problem where it counts.

Comment: Use the exact same method/equations you used in part a). Treat a as a variable, and solve for x. Then finally plug in a=0.

Comment: You should post your work in the question.

Comment: Find a general equation relating x and a. Test the equation with your answer from part c to make sure the equation is right. Then finally plug in a=0 and solve for x.

Comment: I know that to find x when acceleration = 0 you set the force of friction equation equal to force giving you Tcos(theta) = mu(mg - Tsin(theta)) and then you put it in terms of x. I got (1/m)(mu)(m)(g)[x^2 + h^2]^-1/2 = (1/m)Tx + (1/m)(mu)(h)(T) (h being the height of the pulley). I then substitute in my variables m = 1.5kg, h = 0.14m, mu = 0.36, and T = 10N. I guess what I’m asking is if that equation is correct because it worked for a practice problem with different numbers but not the numbers in the problem where it counts.

Comment: Your first equation looks right. But I'm confused by your second equation.

Comment: What is confusing about it? Do you see what is wrong with it?

Comment: see comments in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

$T\cos(\theta) = \mu (mg-T\sin(\theta))$

$\cos(\theta) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+h^2}}$

$\sin(\theta) = \frac{h}{\sqrt{x^2+h^2}}$

plugging these into the original equation we get:

$T\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+h^2}} = \mu (mg-T\frac{h}{\sqrt{x^2+h^2}})$

multiply both sides by $\sqrt{x^2+h^2}$

Is this what you also got?

$Tx = \mu (mg\sqrt{x^2+h^2}-Th)$

Now plug in everything and solve for x. You'll have to isolate the square root. Then square both sides, simplify and use the quadratic formula. What do you get?